# Jekyll deployment with git

Tags: git, deployment, jekyll

I have a Jekyll site with this folder structure:

```
jekyll_site
  _source
    file1 in source
    file2 in source
    etc...
  _deploy
    file1 in deploy
    file2 in deploy
    etc...
```

I have a git repo initialized in jekyll_site and I have two branches master and source.
I want the source branch to only track the _source folder, and master to only track the _deploy folder. Also, I want to push them to a remote repository but make master branch appear as (in the remote repo):

```
master branch
  file1 in deploy
  file2 in deploy
```

Rather than:

```
master branch
  _deploy
    file1 in deploy
    file2 in deploy
```

So I want to shift the whole thing one level up.
Suppose I could create another repo inside deploy just to make it root and push them separately? But maybe it's possible with one repo as well.
Sorry if I overlooked something very obvious, I'm very tired (and very n00b with git).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different things going on here.

- Git isn't designed to have one directory managed on one branch with another directory maintained in a second branch. To manage two directories separately in the way you describe, two Git repos are needed. One repository for `jekyll_site/_source` and the second for `jekyll_site/_deploy`.
- Using two Git repos takes care of moving your "_deploy" files up one level. Since the repository will be created at `jekyll_site/_deploy`, file will deploy to the root.
- If you decide that you still want to use a single repository, don't fight against Git. That is, don't try to use different branches to separately manage the `_source` and `_deploy` directories. Just create one repo at the `jekyll_site` level. With this approach, you'll want to use something in addition to Git for your deployment. Write a simple script the moves the files from `_deploy` to wherever they need to end up.
- Don't try to put one Git repository inside another one. Bad things will happen. (There is a way to do "[Submodules](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial)" but that's not something you want to mess around with until you have more experience with Git.)

Comment: Thanks for stopping by
My main goal is to have my source under version control, because deploy is just a generated folder that is being served from the root (aka the website). So every modification is being made in the source, but since I'm pushing to Github, deploy also has to be under revision control. I've seen people dealing with this numerous ways, like, [having 2nd branch filter to subdirectory](http://davidensinger.com/2013/04/deploying-jekyll-to-github-pages/),[copying the generated files over and over](http://charliepark.org/jekyll-with-plugins/), or just simply repo inside repo style